# How to insert a docstrip tag environment in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex

I am working on literate programming in LaTeX.  Actually, I am coding a lot of `dtx` files, which contain both the code and its documentation.

When working in Emacs, it uses AUCTeX and switches into TeXDoc-mode.

Quite often, I have to insert docstrip options or tags, which look like this:

```
%<*option>
...
%</option>
```

(That is: a percent sign in the first column and than the tag which is enclosed in less/greater brackets `<>`.  The opening tag begins with a asteriks `*`, the closing tag has a slash `/`.  Of course, the name of the tag (here: option) has to be spelled identically.)

I would love to have some kind of Emacs function, which inserts this special kind of enviroment.  Using the classical `LaTeX-environment` is not suited, as it inserts `\begin` and '\end`, which is not what I need.

I didn't find a hint in the manual.

**Edit: I had a [second question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31413/docstrip-support-in-auctex) related to this theme.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own function and hook it into `docTeX` mode with a key binding, e.g. <kbd>C-c g</kbd>

```lisp
(defun my/docTeX-guards ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((guard (TeX-read-string "Guard: ")))
    (LaTeX-newline)
    (unless (equal (char-before) ?%)
      (insert "%"))
    (insert (concat "<*" guard ">"))
    (newline)
    (save-excursion
      (newline)
      (insert (concat "%</" guard ">")))))

(add-hook 'docTeX-mode-hook
           (lambda ()
           (define-key docTeX-mode-map "\C-cg"
                       #'my/docTeX-guards)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works pretty well!  I am very happy!

Comment: @Jan - You're welcome.  Happy TeXing.

Comment: Arash, thank you very much.  I added an `newline` after the last insert.  It works fine.  I am very happy with it.