# DocStrip support in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex

Right now, I am documenting a larger LaTeX package project by converting the files into DocStrip files.  Therefore I am currently creating a lot of `.ins` and `.dtx`-files in Emacs.

Actually I am using AUCTeX, but its support for this tasks lacks a lot of the usual comfort.

For example: in the `.ins`-batchfiles, I very often need to insert constructs as

```
\generate{%
  \usepreamble\stonepreamble%
  \file{tuc-stone.sty}{%
    \from{tuc-version.dtx}{package}%
    \from{tuc-fonts.dtx}{package,tuc-stone}%
    \from{tuc-options.dtx}{default,tuc-stone}%
    \from{tuc-fonts.dtx}{tuc-stone}}%
}%
```

I can of course type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> to insert the macro `\file`.  But in that case, only `\file{}` is inserted.  As you can see, `\file` originally uses two arguments, and I would like Emacs/AUCTeX to ask me for the file name to generate and---ideally---also to ask my from which sources and optionally guards to use, before inserting

```
\file{<filename>}{%
   \from{<sourcefile>}{<guard>}}
```

as result in the current buffer.

Same applies to the `\generate`-macro.

I haven't found any clues on the internet.  Are there any packages, which support this behaviour or do I need to code them myself?

Comment: AUCTeX does not have a style file for `docstrip`.  To your question, I think you have to code it yourself.  Ideally, that code will be part of AUCTeX then `:-)`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I began to work on it.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX doesn't have a style file for `docstrip`.  If you're going to write it for your own purposes, please consider submitting it to AUCTeX as well.

You will have to assign the copyright to FSF.  If you want to start the process, please follow the instructions [described here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=doc/Copyright/request-assign.future;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Arash, I would be really glad, if my code would be accepted by AUCTeX, that would be a great honor.  I have gained so much from free software, that my code will be frei either.

Comment: @Jan - If you have any questions, drop a line to `auctex-devel@gnu.org`.